# Stalker SOC missions retake after expiring

Tags: stalker-shadow-of-chernobyl

Am I able to retake (Get again) the mission after I failed with it??? 
(e.g. expiring time or just simple refuse the mission with the quest giver).

I have no chance to succeed these quests:

- Find the weapon of the Dutyer,
- Destroy the lair of the blood sucker,
- Kill the traitor,

And I am highly hoping that I will be able to retake them...
Because there were a time progressing bug (1day and some minutes later 2hr)...

Thanks,

Comment: Please tell me why am I get -1, because I liked googled a lot, but still not was sure about the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just go back to the person who gave you the quest and you'll be able to talk to them again and get the quest in the same way as you did before. Main (storyline) quests cannot be retaken however, and if you fail a story quest you'll have to revert to a previous save.

Comment: Thanks Bro!
You are fast.
How do I know if a quest is storyline mission or not?
For example Destroy the lair of the blood sucker is a storyline or not?
Thanks!

Comment: @czupe There are only a few of them, and they are defined as quests that must be undertaken in order to complete the game - e.g. Turn off the Brain Scorcher is a quest that must be done to allow the player to access the Chernobyl NPP

Comment: cool, thank you very much. I never seen an expire date on main mission but I will be more carefull...
I hope these are the only main missions:
http://stalker.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_primary_missions

Comment: @czupe That's right. Main missions don't expire, the only way to fail them is to not complete an objective.